# Issue with displaying correct domain values in legend tick

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend, scale

I am working on continuous color legend using d3.interpolateViridis. I have problem in displaying the legend tick values. I want to display my min(at one end) and max(at another end) (domain values) in legend. I tried changing ticks value but no help.

Here is my code snippet:

```
//scale
var colorScale2 = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis).domain([0, 0.38]);
    
//other code
    
var legendscale = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([0, legendheight - margin.top - margin.bottom])
.domain(colorscale.domain());
        
// scale tick
var legendaxis = d3.axisRight()
.scale(legendscale)
.tickSize(16)
.ticks(2);
```

Also, I have shared JS fiddle link where it takes tick as 0.0 and 0.2(this is supposed to be max value: 0.38).

https://jsfiddle.net/shru90/e42vcLy0/30/

Note: My min value is 0 and max is 0.38(which can vary based on data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the axis puts ticks at nice, round values. If there are specific values that you want to have tick marks for, then you can set the [tickValues](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickValues):

```
d3.axisRight()
    .scale(legendscale)
    .tickSize(16)
    .tickValues(legendscale.domain());
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked for me Dan. I had tried tick values before by passing min and max domain value in array and hence it did not worked. The way I was passing was wrong earlier.